# How to communicate between two ec2 instance? (I'm a ruby user)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

My ec2 instance is the server for a ruby application. I want to create another instance and make it as a storage + simple computation centre(for instance compress files), then want to send to the Amazon S3 Server.

I haven't created another instance because it's a bit demanding for me to figure out where to start. Do I have to install server service or do I also have to install Ruby there?

And also, how can I make a post request to the new instance server? For now, the wave blob file is received via "params[:data]" and send it to S3 server (write method). The below is a part of the code.

```
obj = S3_BUCKET.objects[params[:fname]]
      obj.write(
        file: params[:data],
        acl: :public_read
        )

      render :json => {
                          :file_content => "ex1",
                          :body => "ex2"
          }
```

I'm really wanting to learn the concept and understand in depth. Feel free to share any idea about where to start. :)

Best

Answer (score 0):

> Do I have to install server service or do I also have to install Ruby
>   there?

This question is extremely broad. Of course you can't just create a new server and expect it to have all the services you want running on it unless you create the server from a snapshot of an already working server. If you just create a new Linux server from a standard Linux AMI then you will have to install whatever software you want to run on that server.

In general you would need to have a service running on your second server, listening on a specific port, that your application on the first server could call. This could be a REST service listening on a standard HTTP/HTTPS port, or it could be a wide variety of other service types.

Also there is nothing really AWS specific about this, it's just standard Linux server stuff. The only AWS specific items would be opening the Security Groups to allow network communication between the two servers, but you haven't even gotten to that point yet.

> And also, how can I make a post request to the new instance server?

I don't understand this part of your question. Are you saying you want a browser's POST request to be directed directly to the 2nd server instead of the first? More details regarding your application architecture are needed in order to understand what you are asking here, and honestly you should probably post that as a 2nd question, probably after you have a better understanding of what you want to accomplish.

Comment: Hi Mark! Your point is exactly right. My app on the first server records voice data file and it is stored to S3 server with Ajax post request every 1 min. So then how I can setup a service running on my second server to listen on a specific port? ( let's say, my app elastic ip is 52.27.103.211 and second server public ip is 52.37.117.220)? (: I would love to know first part of the question completely.

Comment: "how I can setup a service running on my second server to listen on a specific port" I'm sorry but that question is too broad. It's like asking "how do I do server programming". There are thousands of possible answers to that question. You need to pick a programming language and a data transmission method and then come back and ask a specific question if you still don't understand how to proceed.